# which player ios calls when play html video?

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

I have this website which plays videos, then my ios app shows this website on an UIWebview. My question is that when ios plays video from this website, which player does ios use? I want to know the answer to this question because I want to get pause notification from the player, so I want to know which kind of notification to use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Definitely when iOS plays a video from a website page using native controller, it most probably seems to be a Native iOS player that we can show using MPMoviePlayViewController .

The reason seems to be the VOD or streaming video service must be following Apple's guideline for HLS.

Here is code to listen to StateChange notification

```
MPMoviePlaybackState
Constants describing the current playback state of the movie player.
enum {
   MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped,
   MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying,
   MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward
};
typedef NSInteger MPMoviePlaybackState;
```

Register for the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];

//Check in this function MPMoviePlaybackState

- (void)MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
    if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
    { //playing
    }
    if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
    { //stopped
    }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
    { //paused
    }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted)
    { //interrupted
    }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward)
    { //seeking forward
    }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward)
    { //seeking backward
    }

}
Remove notification by

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

Refer :[MPMoviePlaybackState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMoviePlaybackState)

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that if I want to get a pause notification, then I should listen to MPMoviePlayViewController events?

Comment: Well in that case user has to tap on pause button and yes this can be listened easily.

Comment: But I tried MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification, it doesn't work.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController provides a state change notification (NSNotification object) that you would have to listen to. A Sample code is decsribed below.

Comment: the controller provides "statechange" notification as NSNotification service class object. you should listen to it

Comment: Thanks, where is the definition of player? Under the above condition, the ios app calls a video player automatically.